Unable to use mouse plugged to the usb port
One of usb ports doesn't work with mouse. If I plug the mouse to other port it works. Flash stick is working with all ports.
Logs:
usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71

Is it software or hardware problem?

Usb ports normally functions again. I think it is hardware.
